# Можно ли скрыть коммиты которые вошли в merge request?

Tags: git, gitlab

Если я создаю новую ветку делаю в ней несколько коммитов (test1, test2) и делают мердж в main то в списке коммитов main потом вижу и отдельные коммиты (test1, test2) и объединяющий их мердж.

Как то не совсем логично ведь даже если смотреть на граф то видно что в main поидеи мы должны видеть только мердж, зачем нам видеть эти промежуточные коммиты? (вроде в этом и смысл мерджа)

Но почему то и gitlab и git log упорно показывает эти промежуточные коммиты и мердж коммит как будто они все в ветке main?

Интересно что в main ветке git rev-parse HEAD~1 выдает хеш коммита именно того который шёл до test1,test2 т.е. как я и думал. Но в списке всё равно показываются они как будто в main ветке

[image: example]

[image: example2]

Comment: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/squash_and_merge.html

Comment: Видел это, но тогда просто все коммиты превращаются в один но он так же остается как будто бы в основной ветке + мерджкоммит.
Я просто хочу понять может я что-то не понимаю именно в самой логике процесса, просто по описанию от мерджа ожидал что я не буду видеть коммиты которые вошли в мердж в основной ветке. ?!

Comment: merge-коммит — это просто коммит, который имеет два родительских коммита, и к видимости коммитов это никакого отношения не имеет. И вообще, пытаться скрыть коммиты — плохо, потому что в будущем это затруднит разбирательства с тем, кто-где-когда-зачем написал определённый код

Comment: Не то чтобы скрыть коммиты прям цель. Я просто пытаюсь понять если посмотреть на граф то в main ветке нет этих коммитов они прилетели с мерджем. Почему тогда в списке просмотра коммитов этой ветки - они есть.

Comment: Возможно вы упустили один из главных ньюансов гита - в ветках нет коммитов. Ветка - это ссылка на коммит, а в просмотре показывается цепочка из того коммита, на который сейчас ссылается ветка (`Merge branch 'test2'...`), его предков (`test2` и `Merge branch 'testmerge'...`), и далее рекурсивно.

Answer (score 0):

`git log` показывает HEAD и **всех** его предков.
*Потому что нельзя забывать своих предков!*
Но предков может быть несколько, в гите они занумерованы, и `~` показывает только "родителя №1" (*Да, в гите родители не равноправны, вот такой шовинизм там творится, а вы думали что поменяли master на main и повесточка соблюдена?  Нет.  Простите, отвлёкся*).
Чтобы увидеть любого родителя, нужно индексировать их через `^` (напр, "родитель №2" - `HEAD^2`).